# Read tiff tags in Python

Tags: python, tiff, scikit-image

I am trying to read the tags of a tiff file in Python. The file is RGB with *uint16* values per channel. I am currently using *tifffile*:

```
import tifffile

img = tifffile.imread('file.tif')
```

However, `img` is a numpy array, which only has pixel values. How can I read, for instance, the *x_resolution* of the image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an alternative:

```
import tifffile
with tifffile.TiffFile('file.tif') as tif:
    tif_tags = {}
    for tag in tif.pages[0].tags.values():
        name, value = tag.name, tag.value
        tif_tags[name] = value
    image = tif.pages[0].asarray()
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about `tifffile` lib but you can get `x resolution` with `exifread`:

```
import exifread

with open('image.tif', 'rb') as f:
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
print(tags['Image XResolution'])
```

Output:

```
300
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`skimage.external.tifffile`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.external.tifffile.html) is another possible approach:

```
from skimage.external import tifffile

with tifffile.TiffFile('your_file.tif') as tif:
    imgs = [page.asarray() for page in tif.pages]
    x_res = [page.tags['x_resolution'].value for page in tif.pages]
```

**Edit**: the copy of `tifffile` was removed in [version 0.17.1](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/release_notes.html?highlight=tifffile), and `tifffile` is now installed through pip during the scikit-image installation